# Identifying height/width constraints that are not NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint or similar

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to 'grab' the width/height constraints of a view *generically*, that is, without setting an identifier/tag on the constraints. The system installs other constraints (such as `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint`, but there are other private classes).

They are both `NSLayoutConstraint` class, same `firstItem`, `Attribute` and have similar properties in any property I can think of.

I'm looking for a way to differentiate between the ones I installed and the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using: `NSStringFromClass(type(of:))` or `String(describing: type(of:))`, which will return `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint` or `NSLayoutConstraint`.

```swift
if type(of: constraintInstance) == NSLayoutConstraint.self {
    // This is not a system constraint
}
```

*(Thanks for Dale for the comparison help!)*

Comment: Or type(of: constraintInstance) == NSLayoutConstraint.self